# Regex: Only allow certain format within string

Tags: regex

I am using regex to validate input within a Google form, the input value should only contain the following formats SSDC ,SSFW , SS, HR, TR. For example SSDC66765 should work but SSCD or SSTY should not. I have tried to use the following regex

```
^[A-ZA-Z]{2,4}\d{3,4}$
```

But this does not limit to the following input SSDC ,SSFW , SS, HR, TR

Comment: You have edited away your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten it to an alternation, and not that SSDC66765 has 5 digits so the quantifier can be `{3,5}` instead (or adjust to your needs)

```
^(?:SS(?:FW|DC)?|[HT]R)\d{3,5}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `SS(?:FW|DC)?` Match either SS SSFW or SSDC
  - `|` Or
  - `[HT]R` Match either HR or TR
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\d{3,5}` Match 3 - 5 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6sdHva/1)